# How to show specified column data in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This is my code:

```
public string LoadAllWeeks(int course_id)
        {
            var dbSnapShot = db.CourseWeeks
                .Include(cw=>cw.WeekQuestions)
                .ThenInclude(cq => cq.Qn)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.Answers)
                .Where(c => c.CourseId == course_id);
            var serializedItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbSnapShot, Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
            return serializedItem;
        }
```

This code is returning the complete data of each table but I want it to return only the 2nd columns data of each table. How can I do that?
these are the images of the json I'm getting.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwgYq.png)

Comment: You could create a view model which contains specified columns.Or  you could use anonymous  class.Please share your model and which column you want to display.

Comment: We have made our Asp.NET Core 3.1 project with reverse engineering approach, where we just made tables in sql server and our dbcontext and all model were created automatically by EF Core. So where we can create UserViewModel for this.

Comment: two simple ways I have provided below.You do not share your models,so I just provide a simple demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could create a view model which contains specified columns:

Model(Just an example):

```
public class People
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string peepleName { get; set; }
    public List<Cats> Cats { get; set; }
}
public class Cats
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string catName { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string peepleName { get; set; }
    public string catName { get; set; }
}
```

Display specified columns:

```
var dbSnapShot = _context.People.Include(a => a.Cats).Where(a => a.id == 1)
                        .Select(a => new ViewModel
                        {
                            peepleName = a.peepleName,
                            catName = a.Cats.Select(a=>a.catName).ToList()
                        });
```

2.You could also use anonymous type like below:

```
var dbSnapShot = _context.People.Include(a => a.Cats).Where(a => a.id == 1)
                            .Select(a => new  
                            { 
                                Name =a.peepleName,
                                CName = a.Cats.Select(a=>a.catName)
                            });
```